# Android calendar add recurrence event but only effect for a short time

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-event

im testing android calendar recurrence event. Im have setted an event to android calendar and add a rrule, code like this:

```
public static int addCalendarEvent(Context context, CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {

        checkContextNull(context);

        long calID = obtainCalendarAccountID(context);

        Uri uri1 = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;

        Uri eventUri;
        
        Uri uri2 = CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI;

        Uri reminderUri;
        
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
        setupEvent(calendarEvent, event);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == context.checkSelfPermission(
                    "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR")) {
                eventUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri1, event);
            } else {
                return -2;
            }
        } else {
            eventUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri1, event);
        }

        if (null == eventUri) {
            return -1;
        }

        long eventID = ContentUris.parseId(eventUri);

        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();

        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);

        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        reminderUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri2, reminders);

        if (null == reminderUri) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

the setUpEvent code:

```
private static void setupEvent(CalendarEvent calendarEvent, ContentValues event) {

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calendarEvent.getStart());

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calendarEvent.getEnd());

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, calendarEvent.getTitle());

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, calendarEvent.getDescription());

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, calendarEvent.getEventLocation());

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_DEFAULT);

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, 0);

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
        final String repeatRRule = getFullRRuleForRRule(calendarEvent);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(repeatRRule)) {
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,  repeatRRule);
        }
    }
```

the final rrule:

> "FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20260801T160000Z;BYMONTHDAY=10"

Im try to set monthly repeat event, after setup only three month has events. Then i changed the rrule like:

> "FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=100;BYMONTHDAY=10"

It still the same result.I dont know where is wrong.Can someone help me... Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps BYMONTHDAY instead of BYMOTHDAY?

Comment: Sorry, its my spelling mistake. In my code its "BYMONTHDAY", I have updated thanks.